# onresume not working in sencha

Tags: sencha-touch-2, resume

I am running an application and when i build it in IOS and run it, it runs fine. I have a native application preferences binded to it. So i need to load the data from the application preferences to my application settings when the appllication is resumed.

I tried the code:

```
init: function(){
},
launch: function(){
loaduserpref();
}
resume: function(){
console.log('resumed');
setuserpref();
}
```

but the resume is never called.

What should i  do?